# Load link,href,hyperlink,url in a lightbox or a frame on the current page with refresh the whole page

Tags: ajax, facebook, html, lightbox, frame

I am new to AJAX,

I want to have a javascript that will make all the link(include webpage,internal link, external link) load in a lightbox when clicked. Just like Facebook, when you click the photo, it will give you a frame , without redirect you to the photo page.

Overall, I want my user to click on ANY link of my website do not redirect to a new page which need to refresh the whole page. 
I want the link to be load in a frame on demand, also know as AJAX right?

Actually I just want to know this technique is called as what?? Any google search term ?? searching queries??

Any recommend article or tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29): Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.  Your example isn't AJAX, but rather it's using JavaScript to do *event binding* that causes actions to take place in response to events made by the user in the browser.

You could use jQuery to bind an event to all the links of a certain type on a page.  The exact implementation will depend on your HTML markup.

If, for example, you have several images wrapped in link tags:

```
<a href="image1.jpg" class="image_link"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="image2.jpg" class="image_link"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
```

You could have jQuery similar to the following (be sure to load jQuery prior to this in the page):

```
<script>
$('.image_link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stops it from doing normal link action

    // and then down here you'd need JS for your lightbox library
});
</script>
```

Smashing Magazine has an article that might help you: [Modal Windows in Modern Web Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/27/modal-windows-in-modern-web-design/).